# Laravel 4 - @whatever.com only

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like an input field of an email to be only @whatever.com.
So if a person signs up I want them to only be able to sign up with an address I pick.
Say only emails of @gmail.com, nothing else.
Not sure really on how to do that in laravel 4.
I am still learning laravel.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying where exactly you need that, so I'll assume it's in a form input.

```
list($name, $domain) = split("@", Input::get('email'), 2);

if ($domain !== 'gmail.com')
{
   return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'Invalid domain.');
}
```

You can also create a validator to help you with this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules.

You can create a custom validator to suit your needs:

```
Validator::extend('gmail', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    list($name, $domain) = split("@", $value, 2);

    return $domain !== 'gmail.com';
});
```

And then

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
    array(
        'email'                         => 'required|max:50|email|gmail|unique:users',
        'username'                      => 'required|max:20|min:8|unique:users',
        'password'                      => 'required|min:6',
        'password_again'        => 'required|same:password'
    )
);
```